# How do I insert code between comments in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a shortcode between every fifth comment (or arbitrary value) which will display an ad. My theme is calling the comments as follows:

```
<ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'style'      => 'ol',
                'short_ping' => true,
                'avatar_size' => 60
            ) );
        ?>
</ol><!-- .comment-list -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, you can use a callback function to build the way comments look. http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/customising-wp_list_comments/ this tutorial might help.

Comment: You can use a Walker...

Comment: I looked into the wp page on Walkers, but that's a little over my skill level. :(

Comment: I know this is old question, but I have the same question, and my PHP skill is lacking :( ... Please help

Comment: Did you find a solution @MichaelGregory ??